# Quadratic program reformulation maximum to minimum

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

I am newbie in optimization problem, I have the following optimization problem: 
$$\max \quad \frac{1}{2}x^THx - q^THx$$
$$\text{s.t.} \;\;l\leq x \leq u$$
where $H, q$ are known constants, and H is positive semi-definite, then it's a non-convex problem. I need to reformulate in a standard form (non-convex): 
$$\min \quad \frac{1}{2}x^THx + f^Tx$$
$$\text{s.t.} \quad Ax \leq b, \;\;A_{eq}x=b_{eq}, \;\;l\leq x \leq u$$
Where H is not positive semidefinite.

My first intuition, I hope it's the right one, it was to multiply by -1 the first optimization problem:
$$\min \quad \frac{1}{2}x^TVx + f^T x$$
$$\text{s.t.} \;\;l\leq x \leq u$$
where $V = -H$ and $f = -q^TV$, so my question, is it correct? or which will it be correct reformulation?

Comment: I think your formulation is good.

Comment: Yes, correct as maximizing $f(x)$ is same as minimizing $-f(x)$

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I thought the same thing